# Query to find rows containing ASCII characters in a given range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation, character-set, encoding

I am using some scripts from another topic, but the accepted answer isn't working for all my data scenarios.  I would have asked my question on the original [How to check for Non-Ascii Characters](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/138350/65885) post, but I don't have enough reputation to comment or up-vote as of yet.

**Questions:**

- Why is the [accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/138354/65885) not working for char(150)?
- Is there a way to fix the [accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/138354/65885)?

**My Testing**

I created [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e1e59/4/2) with sample data, the stored procedure from one of the answers, and queries to demonstrate the issue.

> Query 1: sample_table

```
-- Note: The "bad dash" row has char(150)

SELECT * FROM sample_table;

+-------------------+
|    DataColumn     |
+-------------------+
| test - good dash  |
| test – bad dash   |
+-------------------+
```

> Query 2: The [other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/224900/65885) by [John](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/93384/john) shows the "bad dash" row containing char(150):

```
SELECT dbo.Find_Invalid_Chars(DataColumn) [Invalid Characters]
FROM sample_table
WHERE dbo.Find_Invalid_Chars(DataColumn) IS NOT NULL;

+----------------------+
|  Invalid Characters  |
+----------------------+
| test [150] bad dash  |
+----------------------+
```

> Query 3: The [accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/138354/65885) by [Martin Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3690/martin-smith) returns **no results**:

```
SELECT DataColumn AS [Bad Data]
FROM sample_table
WHERE DataColumn LIKE '%[' + CHAR(127)+ '-' +CHAR(255)+']%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2;

+------------+
| [Bad Data] |
+------------+

-- No rows returned.
```

**Conclusion**

Unfortunately, I often need to find characters within (or outside of) a range in databases I can't create stored procedures in.  I'd really like to find a fix for the [accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/138354/65885) or a simple script that wouldn't require creation of any objects (including temp tables).

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:** The solution cannot modify or add any objects or settings in the database. I'm looking for a self-contained query that will select rows with one or more characters in a range between two `CHAR()` numbers, regardless of the ASCII or Extended ASCII number supplied.

**EDIT 2:** The DataColumn can be in either `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`. I have no control over this, so I'm hoping to figure out a self-contained query that works for both. The purpose of the query is to find characters in the source table/column that are not handled correctly by some software applications. The applications are interpreting the source correctly, but sometimes have issues with characters outside "standard" ranges, though the ranges vary by application.

Comment: why your Query 3 is not looking for char(150) ? Try `WHERE DataColumn LIKE '%[' + CHAR(150)+']%'`

Comment: Hi Fred. Can you please be more specific with what you are looking for. Do you just need to find rows that have 1 or more non-ASCII characters? Do you need to find the specific characters in each row that has them? Do you need to replace them? What do you consider to be "non-ASCII"? I only ask because the question you linked to erroneously identifies "`CHAR(1)` through `CHAR(31)`" as "non-ASCII" when those characters are in fact ASCII. Non-ASCII, would more correctly   mean only characters values 128 - 255 (i.e. the Extended ASCII range). Also, what is the default collation of your DB?

Comment: @Squirrel Query 3 looks for a range between 127 and 255.

Comment: @Solomon Rutzky - The term Non-ASCII was from the original poster that I linked to.  I am aware those characters are in fact ASCII.  The query I was looking for would select rows with one or more characters in a range between two CHAR() numbers, regardless of the ASCII or Extended ASCII number supplied.

Comment: @Fred Ok, thanks for clarifying. Now that I understand better I will come up with something and update my answer with it. ALSO, converting string data into a particular code page (hence, `VARCHAR`) from either `NVARCHAR` or `VARCHAR` of a different code page _may_ convert an invalid source character into a valid target character. For example, superscript "**²**" (not standard ASCII) sometimes converts to a regular decimal digit "**2**" (standard ASCII). The list of characters and what they convert to, if anything, is per code page. Which value should this query see: source or target?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky - The purpose of the query is to find characters in the source table/column that are not handled correctly by some software applications.  The applications are interpreting the source correctly, but sometimes have issues with characters outside "standard" ranges, though the ranges vary by application.  

So, I think the answer to your question is "source", since that is what needs to be evaluated.  **EDIT** Hmm.. maybe not... The idea is to enter the Dec value from [link](http://www.asciitable.com/) into CHAR() to represent the Char column.  Does that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the accepted answer not working for char(150)?

Actually, it does. The problem is your test is bad / invalid. You test column, `DataColumn`, is using `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`. The character itself works in both datatypes, but the behavior is different due to how it is being used in each case:

- In the `Find_Invalid_Chars()` function (i.e. the "other" answer), the string is being converted back into `VARCHAR` since that is the datatype of the input parameter for that function. In this case it works as expected (although I believe it can be done much more efficiently than that loop, but that's for another time ;-)
- In the `LIKE` query (i.e. the "accepted" answer), the expanded and concatenated result of `'%[' + CHAR(127)+ '-' +CHAR(255)+']%'` is actually converted into `NVARCHAR` since that is the datatype of the column it is being compared to (and `NVARCHAR` has a higher datatype precedence), hence that `LIKE` function is *not* behaving as expected: either the `CHAR(255)` character maps to a different code point, and/or the `CHAR(150)` character in the column itself maps to a different code point (the `CHAR(127)` character does not change as it's in the standard ASCII range). In either case, the conversion to `NVARCHAR` is causing the numerical value of the "En Dash" character ("–") to no longer be within that range. Meaning, the `LIKE` function is looking for values, `y`, between `127` and `x` (where `x` >= 128), and `y` for the "En Dash" character is now > `x`. Whereas in `VARCHAR`, `x` = 255 and `y` = 150.

The quick fix to see that it does work is simply to change the `NVARCHAR` datatype of the  `DataColumn` column to be `VARCHAR` (yes, just remove the initial "N"), then re-build the schema, then execute, and the `LIKE` query will behave as expected.

The following might help explain why making the test column `NVARCHAR` caused the `LIKE` query to not match the row:

```sql
SELECT UNICODE(CHAR(127)) AS [CHAR(127)],
       UNICODE(CHAR(150)) AS [CHAR(150)],
       UNICODE(CHAR(255)) AS [CHAR(255)];

/*
CHAR(127)     CHAR(150)     CHAR(255)
127           8211          255
*/
```

As you can see in the results below the query, the "bad dash", which was `CHAR(150)` became `NCHAR(8211)` when stored in the `NVARCHAR` column. And, since that predicate is using a binary collation (generally the correct thing to do in this scenario), it was looking at the code points / values, not the characters. Hence, the `LIKE` clause was looking for characters with values between 127 and 255, and 8211 is typically not in that range ;-).

**P.S.** Please keep in mind that the function `CHAR(150)` *can* return different characters, or even `NULL`, based on the default collation of the database in which you execute that function. This is because `VARCHAR` data is based on code pages, and those are determined by the collation, and the collation being used when executing the `CHAR()` function is the default collation of the active / current database. This affects values 128 - 255. Values 0 - 127 will always return the same characters, regardless of collation, as those are the standard ASCII character set and are the same across all of the code pages supported in SQL Server (though not in all code pages in general).

**P.P.S.** ALSO, I just noticed a slight difference in logic between the function and the query (i.e. the two answers from the linked question): `CHAR(127)` is considered good / valid in the `Find_Invalid_Chars()` function, yet it's considered bad / invalid in the `LIKE` query. If it were me, I would consider `CHAR(127)` valid as it's part of the standard ASCII character set. But, you need to decide what you consider it. Just be aware of that difference in case you do need to adjust the `LIKE` syntax a little.

---

Given:

1. > The purpose of the query is to find characters in the source table/column that are not handled correctly by some software applications.

   and:
2. > The data can be in either VARCHAR or NVARCHAR.

I would say that:

1. You *don't* want to convert `NVARCHAR` source data into `VARCHAR` as there might be "best fit" mappings that translate invalid source characters into valid characters, but one or more of your software applications might not use "best fit" mappings.

   ```sql
   SELECT NCHAR(178) AS [Unicode], -- Superscript 2 (U+00B2)
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), NCHAR(178)
                      COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS [CodePage-1252],
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), NCHAR(178)
                      COLLATE Turkmen_100_CI_AS) AS [CodePage-1250]

   /*
   Unicode    CodePage-1252    CodePage-1250
   ²          ²                2
   */
   ```
2. It will likely be more reliable to look for characters *not* in a specific "valid" range as opposed to those in a specific invalid range, especially when dealing with `NVARCHAR` which holds *a lot* more than 256 characters.
3. You could get away with a single query *if* the "valid" range is always between values 0 and 127 (since those values are the same in both cases). But if you need to specify values above 127, then you will need one query for `VARCHAR` and one for `NVARCHAR`.

All that being said:

- The following query returns rows containing at least one character that is *not* in the range of 0 - 127, for both `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR`. But, it only works with `NVARCHAR` columns for values above 127.

  ```sql
  SELECT *
  FROM   (VALUES (NCHAR(178)), (NCHAR(8211)), (N''), (NULL), (N'xy' + NCHAR(165)),
             (N'AA'), (N'mM' + NCHAR(999) + N'Nn'), (N'#!~()')) tmp(TestValue)
  WHERE  tmp.[TestValue] LIKE N'%[^' + NCHAR(0) + N'-' + NCHAR(127)
            + N']%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2;

  /*
  TestValue
  ²
  –
  xy¥
  mMϧNn
  */
  ```
- The following query also returns rows containing at least one character that is *not* in the range of 0 - 127, but only works for `VARCHAR` columns. However, it does allow using values between 128 and 255.

  ```sql
  SELECT *
  FROM   (VALUES (CHAR(178)), (CHAR(150)), (''), (NULL), ('AA'), ('#!~()'),
          ('xy' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), NCHAR(165) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2)),
          ('mM' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), NCHAR(199) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2) + 'Nn')
         ) tmp(TestValue)
  WHERE  tmp.[TestValue] LIKE '%[^' + CHAR(0) + '-' + CHAR(127)
            + ']%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2;

  /*
  TestValue
  ²
  –
  xy¥
  mMÇNn
  */
  ```

---

Regarding:

> The applications are interpreting the source correctly, but sometimes have issues with characters outside "standard" ranges, though the ranges vary by application.

1. Not sure I understand how there can be "issues" with some characters if the app is interpreting the source data correctly, unless you meant that they "mostly" interpret the data correctly.
2. The ranges varying by application sound like this might require more detailed investigation than can be done in a simple Q & A format such as this. This behavior can be due to them using different drivers to connect (ODBC / OLEDB / etc), what language they are written in, what assumptions they are making about the data they are getting, and so on. Some problems might be fixable with a configuration (no code change) of the app, some might be fixable only with a code change, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, it was quite educational and much appreciated.  Unfortunately, I can't use the provided solution as it would require modifying an object (table) in the database.  I'm going to try playing around with converting NVARCHAR to VARCHAR in the query, but not sure that will resolve the issue.  Also, I am not sure how to solve the issue of different collation in the database.  Any other suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: Hi @Fred . Ok. To be fair, there's no indication in the question that your column is _actually_ `NVARCHAR` as everything is in terms of `VARCHAR` (string literals, referenced question only deals with `VARCHAR`, use of `CHAR()` instead of `NCHAR()`, etc). It certainly looked like the use of `NVARCHAR` in the SQL Fiddle demo wasn't exactly intentional. Your source data being `NVARCHAR` is a critical detail that needs to be added to the question. I'll update my answer soon to account for this. Converting to `VARCHAR` may or may not work, depending on the exact goal (will comment on question).

Comment: Hi @Soloman.  Understood, I'll update the question.  FYI - Whatever solution I find needs to work regardless of VARCHAR or NVARCHAR, as the databases I'm trying to evaluate could have either.  Sorry if this is getting more complicated than you expected.  Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: @Soloman Thanks for all the great detail. Your example using `not in the range of 0 - 127` worked perfectly! Much appreciated, I learnt a lot.

Comment: @Fred You're welcome. Glad it helped. To be clear, both of the examples at the end find rows "not in the range of 0 - 127". I updated the wording on the 2nd one to make it clearer that it a) did the same "not in 0 - 127 range" as the first one, and b) only works for `VARCHAR`, and c) allows for using full 0 - 255 range for `VARCHAR` (which the first query can't do, at least not reliably). Take care..